# GeoDjango. Admin not showing map location for point = models.PointField() in created instances

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to create member instances in a very simple way to practice GeoDjango. I am able to create the instances but they are not showing correctly in the admin map **(See images Below)**

below are my **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

    class Member(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        image = models.ImageField()
        lat = models.FloatField()
        lon = models.FloatField()
        point = models.PointField()
        objects = models.GeoManager()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

below is my **views.py**

```
class MemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Member
    fields = ('name', 'image', 'lat', 'lon')

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.point = fromstr('POINT(%s %s)'%(self.object.lat, self.object.lon), srid=4326)
        self.object.save()
        return redirect('member:all_members')
```

The model and views are successfully creating the model instance on my admin.py below is the code for **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis import admin
from .models import Member

admin.site.register(Member, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)
```

**The point on Admin of my GeoDjango Project See Below**
[image]
**The place where the point actually is on the internet( Notice same lat, lon See Below)**
[image]

How can I fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changed this

```
self.object.point = fromstr('POINT(%s %s)'%(self.object.lat, self.object.lon), srid=4326)
```

to

```
self.object.point = fromstr('POINT(%s %s)'%(self.object.lon, self.object.lat), srid=4326)
```

The lon comes before lat.